# Create all possible correlation matrices for 3 variables

Tags: r, correlation, normal-distribution

I would like to simulate 3 variables (normally distrubted with mean=1 and sd=1) that have a specific correlation structure.

For each variable I would like to go through the correlation values 0.1 to 0.9 with increments of 0.1

SO possible correlations of the three variables would be

```
X1  X2  X3
0.1 0.1 0.1
0.1 0.1 0.2
0.1 0.1 0.3
..
0.9 0.9 0.9
```

In the end I would like to use these three correlation values to construct a variance-covariance matrix.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you would like to generate a set of (possibly) 729 data-sets each with a different correlation structure?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: OK, then be careful that some of your "correlation matrices" are actually not correlation matrices: they will have negative eigenvalues. For example the combination 0.8  0.7  0.1 will give something that is not a correlation matrix. (I ran some computations and I think this concerns 78 out of the 729 possible combinations)

Comment: That's fine. I can just skip those cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the r package *mvtnorm*.

Define your correlation matrix `s`, and simulate the variable like this:

```
x<-rmvnorm(n, mean = rep(0, nrow(sigma)), sigma = s)
```

Now you can construct a loop, and go through all combinations of s, which you want.

Comment: I think one could use `mapply` here instead of explicit loops, e.g. `do.call(mapply,c(FUN=function(i,j,k) {i+j+k},expand.grid(i=1:3,j=1:3,k=1:3)))`